# What Glacier vault does S3 default to?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, notifications, amazon-glacier

Relating to (or following on from) the question: [How does AWS transfer S3 objects to Glacier archives when you use lifecycle archive rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835209/how-does-aws-transfer-s3-objects-to-glacier-archives-when-you-use-lifecycle-arch) - where it is explained that S3 is essentially just another multi-tennanted 'customer' of Glacier - does that mean I'm completely unable to configure notification events on the 'default' Glacier vault?

In S3, I'm unable to specify a vault to archive to, so are Glacier notifications only of purpose for bespoke apps that use the API's to handle their storage needs?

I'd really like to enable notifications on archive retrieval (and 'restored item expiry' if *possible*) - and I've already vaulted a huge stack of things via S3 - into 'the default vault of concealment'.

Is it a turd or am I just doing it wrong? (go on, be honest)?

(EDIT: sorry, forgot question mark)

Comment: It seems like this is fairly well addressed in the other answer: *"your ability to interact with Glacier, directly, when S3 is archiving objects there for you is non-existent."*

Comment: You're right - I kinda missed the subtleties didn't i?

Answer (score 4):

It is concealed.

When archiving from Amazon S3 to Amazon Glacier, there is no ability to configure the back-end vault, nor its notifications. There is also no notification from S3 available to notify of restorations/deletions.

Comment: Drive-by comment here (and maybe a nitpick but wanted to clarify): did you mean it as written or is it supposed to be "when archiving TO Amazon Glacier FROM Amazon S3"?  Came across this while searching for smth else but this struck me as maybe a typo?

Comment: Yes, you are right -- Archiving goes from S3 to Glacier. Oopsie!

Comment: I edited the post to avoid the confusion to possible future readers @JohnRotenstein