# invoke lambda to with parameter 4 hours later

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need help figuring out how to pass an array of s3 file names to my second aws lambda function I am working on. The first function would query the dynamodb index table for list of s3 files in glacier it would issue retrieval request to. the second lambda would get the same filename parameter in an array one at a time and invoke the lambda function but 4 hours later for each of the files that are retrieved from Glacier, is there any delicate way to do this in lambda or other AWS services using javascript? any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098943/what-glacier-vault-does-s3-default-to and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835209/how-does-aws-transfer-s3-objects-to-glacier-archives-when-you-use-lifecycle-arch.

Answer (score 2):

Glacier retrieval jobs are not guaranteed to be complete within 4 hours (archives typically become accessible [within 3–5 hours](https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/details/), but that's not a guarantee). Also, scheduling Lambda function invocations for some time in the future is not the best way to solve this problem.

You should make use of [Glacier notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/configuring-notifications.html#configuring-notifications.general).  When a Glacier retrieval job completes, it can post a message to an SNS topic. SNS and Lambda are integrated so you can invoke Lambda functions from SNS notifications.

The Glacier SDK supports archive retrieval (and inventory retrieval) with SNS notifications at completion time via [initiate_job()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/glacier.html#Glacier.Client.initiate_job).

EDIT: this does not work if the S3 objects were archived to Glacier via [lifecycle management](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) because retrieval notifications require you to supply a Glacier vault name but lifecycle management does not expose this vault name to you (it's internal to the AWS service). [Thanks [@Mark B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13070/mark-b)]

Comment: what if I am using the S3 life-cylce glacier storage class? is there an Glacier notification as well or is that just for glacier vault?

Comment: GLACIER is a single S3 storage class (and Glacier is the service itself). There's no "lifecycle glacier" or "glacier vault" storage class. Vaults are containers that store archives. Lifecycle (management) is the process of using a set of rules that automate the transition of objects between storage classes (though not *from* Glacier).

Comment: @jarmod I think the question is, once an S3 lifecycle rule has transitioned an object to the Glacier storage class, and then something initiates a retrieval of that object, like through a call to boto3 `s3_client.restore_object()`, can you get a Glacier notification? Or any other notification? I don't see how to personally. You don't have access to the underlying Glacier vault so you can't configure notifications to occur. And S3 doesn't appear to have any sort of "restore completed" event notification.

Comment: @MarkB I don't personally use Glacier, but the docs indicate that "You can also optionally specify an Amazon SNS topic in each job initiation request". Digging a little deeper it seems that none of the S3 SDKs for restore object include an SNS topic parameter, however the Glacier SDK supports an SNS topic in initiate_job(). It looks like you can use this to request retrieval of an archived object, and get a notification via SNS.

Comment: @jarmod the glacier `initate_job()` method requires a vault name. That isn't available when you are using S3 lifecycle rules, because the underlying Glacier vault isn't exposed to you.

Comment: @MarkB Got it. I should spend more time with Glacier ;-)